# Is there a way to have multiple full-page containers in Bootstrap? (specifications noted inside)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble with making multiple full-page containers in bootstrap. 
Specifically, I want my pages to be one after the other, similar to this demonstration (I am not the author): https://codepen.io/butsuri/pen/xcukz

The issue that I'm running into is that most implementations of the full-page containers don't rely on Bootstrap containers, and I need Bootstrap containers because I don't want to mess up the text alignment in my code (if I implemented my code the same way as above, the padding in my "tabs" would be removed).

If my explanation/code is awful (I'm sorry), here is what I have so far: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwjzWY

and I want to have more fullpage divs after this, but adding in other containers just squishes it since it'll share the row's h-100 (making it h-50, h-33, and so on, each), and it won't be fullscreen (100vh) anymore.

I feel like I am missing something incredibly basic. Thank you for helping me (whoever you are) in advance.

My code is:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
            <div class="card-block mx-auto">
                <p style="margin:0">public class Class {
                    <p style="padding-left:5em;margin:0">
                    Stylised, indented tabs
                    </p>
                    }
                </p>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you forgot to close the `div` after `p` tag. check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEpZmP

Comment: Applying `height: 100vh;` to `.container` makes rather little sense to begin with, unless you want to repeat that element around each of those full-screen sections. And `h-100` on the row element makes rather little sense if you want to put multiple of those sections into one row element. Forcing the row to be 100% or 100vh high would only make sense, if you had one column element representing such a full-screen section per row - if you need it to be multiple columns per row, because you need a different layout for mobile or something, that won’t work.

Comment: @MinalChauhan thank you so much, I feel like an idiot now haha

Comment: @04FS Could you help me out with my coding style? I realised how bad the style was but I'm not sure how to fix it. Specifically, the h-100 on the "row" element makes it so that it centers the text that I have inside and leaving it out makes it so that the row only takes as much space as it needs starting from the top (please correct me if I'm wrong), and I know the way I'm doing it is terrible but not sure what I should be doing instead to make the text perfectly centered (without using text-align).